# Why code runs unstably on Arduino esp8266?

Tags: arduino, iot, arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

Here is my code that I flashed to my esp8266 (esp-01) with Arduino IDE. I tried flashing multiple times but sometimes it succeeded for the first run and resets at second run or power loss and sometimes it doesn't run at all.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <Firebase.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <FirebaseCloudMessaging.h>
#include <FirebaseError.h>
#include <FirebaseHttpClient.h>
#include <FirebaseObject.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <AutoConnect.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
//getting time and date
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#define FIREBASE_HOST "arduino-9ac24.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "NtHBXaYlV5PGn4cWBTFG5dmjfsbICFpJzc1hle1o"
ESP8266WebServer Server;
AutoConnectConfig Config; 
AutoConnect Portal(Server);
WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP,5);
String data;
void setup() {
  Serial.println("Module Started"); 
  //esp.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Portal.begin();
  Serial.println("Server:"+WiFi.localIP().toString());
  //Portal.config(Config);
  Config.autoReconnect = true;
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH); 
  timeClient.begin();
} 

void loop() {
  Portal.handleClient();
  timeClient.update();
  if (Firebase.failed()) {
    Serial.println(Firebase.error());
    Serial.println("Trying to reconnect....");
    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  }
  else{
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      while (Serial.available() > 0) {
          data = Serial.read();          //data is the incoming data
     }
      Firebase.setString("/sensor_1/"+timeClient.getFormattedDate(), data);
      Serial.println(data);
    }
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

Here is the output

```sh
14:43:31.005 -> load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16  
14:43:31.005 -> ecting..........................(IP unset), DNS1=(IP unset), DNS2=(IP unset))
14:43:31.005 -> [AC] DHCP cli⸮⸮QIQ⸮
14:43:31.005 -> [AC] WiFi.begin() 
14:43:31.005 -> [AC] Connecting..................................timeout IP:(IP unset) 
14:43:33.594 -> [AC] SoftAP configure 172.217.28.1, 172.217.28.1, 255.255.255.0  
14:43:42.952 -> 
14:43:42.952 ->  ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,7) 
14:43:42.952 -> 
14:43:42.952 -> wdt reset
```

Comment: [try this](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1328#issuecomment-168291624) And please search for `rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,7)` on the interwebs as this is telling you why the problem happend.

Comment: hey, thanks for reply i'm not actually using any capacitors or resistors, i tried using resistors but looks like it wasn't getting enough power.

Comment: how do you power the esp8266?

Comment: i tried powering using usb ports on pc, 9v external battery and powerbank. nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the watchdog is resetting your ESP because your loop takes too long. This is done to avoid being stuck in endless loops and can happen when you perform lenghty tasks which block the loop for several seconds. I assume that Firebase begin takes too long to connect, especially because you do not check if you are already connected to the wifi before you call it.

Usually, you can solve this problem by making sure that your loop is not blocked for extend time periods. I would suggest you change your code to something like this:

```
void connect(){
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

    Serial.print("connecting");

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(500); // delay will give the esp framework some time to manage wifi stuff and reset the watchdog, so this is fine
    }

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("connected: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    // now we are sure that we are connected, so we can
    // call firebase begin and can be sure that it will not block
    // until the wifi eventually connects.
    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
}

void setup(){

    // setup everything that does NOT need a network connection here

    connect();

    // setup everything that DOES need a network connection here

}

void loop(){

    // The same logic applies here. As long as we are not connected,
    // we do not wan't to execute some network code and risk blocking
    // the loop for so long that the watchdog kicks in, therefore we
    // call the connect function and return afterwards to start
    // the loop over (we do this to give the esp framework time to
    // do network stuff and reset the watchdog)
    if( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ){
        connect();
        return;
    }

    // your regular code

}
```

If you want to learn more about the ESPs watchdog, I'd recommend you read this: https://www.sigmdel.ca/michel/program/esp8266/arduino/watchdogs_en.html#ESP8266_HW_WDT